# 503 upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: local reset - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, istio

I am getting error **503 service unavailable upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: local reset** while making a rest call in my spring boot microservice. I am using Istio as API gateway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue in istio api url. It was not configured properly.

Comment: what was the issue? I am getting same issue.

Comment: URL string was incorrect